# Retrieving values from array of records without losing data if key is missing in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working with GA4 data in BigQuery, which contains a field called `event_params` which a repeated record with subfields `key` and `value`. Essentially the field might contain any number of keys and values.

```
event_params.key | event_params.value
-------------------------------------
foo              | 1
bar              | x
abc              | test
xyz              | example
```

To my knowledge, the best way to extract a value for a particular key is to unnest the field and then filter on the key, e.g.

`SELECT *, ep.value AS foo FROM table, UNNEST(event_params) AS ep WHERE ep.key = 'foo'`

This will return all of the fields in the table + the value of the foo key extracted from `event_params`.

However, any row in which `foo` isn't present in `event_params` will be excluded from the results. I would like to avoid this. One approach is to just UNION ALL back in any row that was excluded:

```
SELECT *, ep.value AS foo FROM table, UNNEST(event_params) AS ep WHERE ep.key = 'foo'
UNION ALL
SELECT *, NULL AS foo FROM table WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'foo'
```

This works just fine. However, this starts to become very complicated if I'm trying to extract multiple keys at once. Imagine:

```
SELECT
  *,
  ep_foo.value AS foo,
  ep_bar.value AS bar,
  ep_abc.value AS abc,
  ep_xyz.value AS xyz
FROM
  TABLE,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS ep_foo,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS ep_bar,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS ep_abc,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS ep_xyz
WHERE
  ep_foo.key = 'foo'
  AND ep_bar.key = 'bar'
  AND ep_abc.key = 'abc'
  AND ep_xyz.key = 'xyz'
```

In this case it starts to become impractical to do the UNION ALL with WHERE NOT EXISTS, as I'll have to have a separate union for each possible combination of keys that could exist or not exist within `event_params`. This isn't reasonably scalable if we decide to extract more keys in future, for example.

The only idea that comes to mind is to start with the table and then left join to subqueries that unnest each individual key, but there's no field that uniquely identifies each row and so I don't see how I could accomplish this join because there's nothing to join on.

Is there a better way to do this? Specifically:

- Is this approach with multiple unnests the best way to extract values from keys in a situation like this to begin with?
- How can I make sure to retain every row in the table if keys are missing from `event_params`?